# When exactly is a callback function executed?

Tags: ros, c++, ros-melodic, callback, spin

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello, I know that in general a callback function is executed when its associated topic has published values.

What I am wondering is how do the commands spin() and spinOnce() in main affect the callback's execution, because I noticed that when the spin() command is in practice not executed like in the code below the callback is also never executed even though messages are published to the topic

```
  ros::Rate loop_rate(0.1);
  while(ros::ok()){
    ROS_INFO("Loop: %d\n",stop_msg.data);
    stop_pub.publish(stop_msg);
    loop_rate.sleep();
  }
  ros::spin();
```

on the other hand, when I changed the code in main to the following everything worked perfectly:

```
  ros::Rate loop_rate(0.1);
  while(ros::ok()){
    ROS_INFO("Loop: %d\n",stop_msg.data);
    stop_pub.publish(stop_msg);
    loop_rate.sleep();
    ros::spinOnce();
  }
```

Could somebody enlighten me?
Thank you

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/346854/when-exactly-is-a-callback-function-executed?/) by [smarn](https://answers.ros.org/users/51434/smarn/) on ROS Answers with karma: 54 on 2020-03-16

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I would suggest you to read the [wiki about Callbacks and Spinning](http://wiki.ros.org/roscpp/Overview/Callbacks%20and%20Spinning), from the introduciton :

> The end result is that without a little bit of work from the user your subscription, service and other callbacks will never be called. The most common solution is ros::spin()

In your first code `ros::spin()` is outside the while loop so it's never called so neither are your callbacks. In your second code you are actually *spinning* so the behavior you describe is totally normal.

Now you should see some related questions to understand the concept of *spinning* : [#q257361](https://answers.ros.org/question/257361/what-is-the-actual-meaning-of-rosspin/), [#q11887](https://answers.ros.org/question/11887/significance-of-rosspinonce/).

---

Originally posted by [Delb](https://answers.ros.org/users/33811/delb/) with karma: 3907 on 2020-03-17

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1